# LaTeX with .eps embedded psfrags

Tags: eps, dvips, psfrag

I have encountered a problem with embed tags (psfrags) in .eps figures. On some of my figures it works beautiful, using the `\tex[][][][]{}` command on the figure and `\psfragscanon` in the figure environment.

But some `.eps` figures ends the document when it is compiled (as if I have put a `\enddocument` in there). This document I have tried compiling on other PC's as well, but same result. There's no warnings or errors, the document is only compiled up until that specific figure and no more. I can't seem to find any consistency in what could cause this problem.

Anyone with a possible solution?
I'm compiling with Latex - dvips - ps2pdf in texmaker on windows.

.eps figures are made in illustrator and inkscape (.eps from both programs causes the problem). Removing the \psfragscanon command works as for including the .eps file, but then of course no tags are translated.

**Update - MWE**

**---**

% The MWE can be downloaded from: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B19aux9V0MGlei1tQjg2eTluamM

% Here the document is named 'EPS_document' and an .eps figure named 'graphic' is the example of causing the above mentioned problem. I have played with different font types and it seems like changing the font type sometimes works as for including the .eps file, but I have not been able to get it working with replacing the tags also. Another figure is included in the above link 'graphic-couriernew' which is with another font type, and then figure is included, but tags are not replaced.

**---**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,dvipsnames,twoside,openright,table]{memoir} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english]{babel}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}                                      
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{psfragx}

\begin{document}

Here is some text. Graphics below.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\psfragscanon
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{graphic}
\caption{Graphic}
\end{figure}

Here is some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: MWE is now added.